# ShellExecuteEx command is successful in Isapi but not CGI

Tags: delphi, iis, cgi, isapi, htmldoc

I am using Delphi Tokyo 10.2. I have the following function:

```
function THtmlToPdfService.ExecuteShell(filename, outFilename : string) : Boolean;
var
  shellInfo : TShellExecuteInfo;
  exitCode : DWORD;
begin
  Result := false;
  try
    // Set Shell execution information
    FillChar(shellInfo, SizeOf(shellInfo), 0);
    shellInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
    shellInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    shellInfo.Wnd := 0;
    shellInfo.lpFile := PChar(GetHtmlDocInstallDirectory + 'htmldoc.exe');
    shellInfo.lpParameters := PChar(Format(' --webpage --datadir ' +
      GetHtmlDocInstallDirectory + ' -f %s %s', [outFilename, filename]));
    shellInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;

    // Run ShellExecuteEx to wait for process to complete
    if ShellExecuteEx(@shellInfo) then
    begin
      repeat
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        GetExitCodeProcess(shellInfo.hProcess, exitCode) ;
      until (exitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE);

      if FileExists(outFilename) then
        Result := true
      else
        RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
  except
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

This, very simply, executes HTMLDoc.exe, using the filename as the source HTML file and outFilename as the target output PDF file. I have the same unit used in both an Isapi DLL and a CGI EXE, running on my localhost. I have a local test exe that calls the web services from my localhost, and when I call the Isapi service, it works just fine...the output PDF is created, and the function that calls this one returns that PDF to the user as a byte array. When I call the CGI service from the same test module, it will not create the output PDF, it simply returns:

```
System Error.  Code: 2.  The system cannot find the file specified
```

Everything else works just fine, but it won't create the output file I need. I have tried permissions, authentication, I've tried different means of formatting the files, I even tried creating the PDF first, hoping that it was simply a matter of having the file already there, even though this doesn't matter to the Isapi service. I have verified that HTMLDoc and the source file can both be found at the point this command executes, and if I create the PDF first the service returns the blank PDF to the user, but I need the HTML file to convert properly in the CGI. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you using `ShellExecute()` at all?  You are running an `.exe` file, so you should be using `CreateProcess()` instead, which `ShellExecute()` is just going to call anyway, so cut out the middleman. Also, I strongly suggest you NOT use a busy loop to call `Application.ProcessMessages()` and `GetExitCodeProcess()` like you are.  Use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` in a loop instead. Exit the loop when it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` when the process terminates, and call `Application.ProcessMessages()` only when it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0+1` to signal the message queue has pending messages.

Comment: Using ShellExecute because I'd never run a command-line process from a Delphi program until now. I'm unfamiliar with the options available for doing so. I will give your suggestion a try and let you know what happens. Thank you!